# Package like `multicol` that supports more than 10 columns

Tags: packages

I'm trying to fit a lot of words onto a single page. However when I use `\begin{multicols}{11}`, I get an error: "Too many columns". Are there any other packages that provide the same kind of automatic positioning that the `multicol` package does?

Comment: In exactly which context do you need more than 10 columns? This sounds like the wrong tool

Comment: This is a legitimate question. I myself needed on one occasion 9 columns, in a list of short words in a landscape page.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/237

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You need a contiguous run of boxes, but these days there are 32 thousand not 256 so you can afford to discard the ones allocated already and allocated a new batch

(actually care should be taken that this range doesn't span 255, not done here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\multicols{\col@number>10}{\col@number>20}{\typeout{OK}}{\typeout{OOPS}}

% old
\newbox\mult@rightbox
\newbox\mult@grightbox
\newbox\mult@gfirstbox
\newbox\mult@firstbox
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa
%new
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
\newbox\@tempa\newbox\@tempa
% end new
\let\@tempa\relax
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{20}
 \raggedright
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, the old "penny in the fusebox" approach.  ;-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo no penny in the fusebox  (the patch of 10 to 20) but then rewire the house to make that safe  (all the newbox) and contact the electricity company (email to Frank:-)

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/237

Comment: changed/fixed in dev version of LaTeX and will show up in the next -dev release and eventually in the next full release of LaTeX.  For those who can't wait, see link by David.